# Link numeric hashtags to a different url than hashtags that include numbers and letter

Tags: php, regex

I need to match hashtags that only include numbers and link them to a different URL than hashtags that include both numbers and letters.

So far I have this:

```
function convertHashtags($str){ 

    $number = "/#+([0-9]+)/"; 
    $mixed = "/#+([0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+)/";

    $str = preg_replace($number, '<a href="/thread/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $str); 
    $str = preg_replace($mixed, '<a href="/search/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>', $str); 

    return($str);
}
```

But they're not working exactly as I want them to.

For example: #remy5648 becomes:

```
<a href="/search/remy" target="_blank">#remy</a>5648
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/thread/remy5648" target="_blank">#remy5648</a>
```

Another example: #65d987 becomes:

```
<a href="/thread/65" target="_blank">#65</a>d987
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/thread/65d987" target="_blank">#65d987</a>
```

What do I need to add to match the whole word instead of just part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to refine the match:

```php
$str = preg_replace_callback('/#([a-z0-9]+)/', function($match) {
  $tag = $match[1];
  $url = is_numeric($tag) ? '/thread/' . $tag : '/search/' . $tag;
  return '<a href="' . $url . '">#' . $tag . '</a>';
}, $str);
```

You probably don't want to replace twice, because the second replace might replace markup created by the first.

Comment: This worked perfectly! The only modification I had to do was change the regex to: /#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9\/\.]` will match `/` and `.`. Was that your intention? If your tags can contain `/`, you should `urlencode($tag)` in `$url`.

Comment: My mistake. I tested the wrong file and was getting the same results as before. I just tested your original answer and it works perfectly. No need to change the regex. Sorry about that, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Add numbers to your regex like that. You can also remove your first preg_replace. What's his goal ?

```
function convertHashtags($str)
{
    //$number = "/#+([0-9]+)/";
    $mixed = "/#+([0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/";

    /*$str = preg_replace(
        $number,
        '<a href="/thread/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>',
        $str
    );*/
    $str = preg_replace(
        $mixed,
        '<a href="/thread/$1" target="_blank">$0</a>',
        $str
    );

    return ($str);
}
```

When I do that, I get your expected values :

```
<a href="/thread/remy5648" target="_blank">#remy5648</a>
<a href="/thread/65d987" target="_blank">#65d987</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your answer fixed the problem when the hashtag starts with a letter. But if it starts with a number it still only matches the first part. For example #65d987 will only match #65.

Comment: After rechecking I noticed the second preg_replace will match numeric hast tags too instead of ignoring them.

Comment: I edited my code and fixed it, sorry. You can retry if you want.